# Vpython using Spyder : how to prevent browser tab from opening?

Tags: python, spyder, vpython

I am using vpython library in spyder. After importing the library when I call simple function like print('x') or carry out any assignment operation and execute the program, immediately a browser tab named localhost and port address opens up and I get the output in console {if I used print function}.

I would like to know if there is any option to prevent the tab from opening and is it possible to make the tab open only when it is required.

PS : I am using windows 10, chrome as browser, python 3.5 and spyder 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

There is work in progress to prevent the opening of a browser tab when there are no 3D objects or graph to display. I don't know when this will be released.

Comment: The recent release of vpython 7.5.0 fixes the problem.